# How to pass an object as props with vue router?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have the following fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/91vLms06/1/

```
const CreateComponent = Vue.component('create', {
  props: ['user', 'otherProp'],
  template: '<div>User data: {{user}}; other prop: {{otherProp}}</div>'
});

const ListComponent = Vue.component('List', {
  template: '<div>Listing</div>'
});

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router: new VueRouter(),
  created: function () {
    const self = this;
        // ajax request returning the user
    const userData = {'name': 'username'}

    self.$router.addRoutes([
      { path: '/create', name: 'create', component: CreateComponent, props: { user: userData }},
      { path: '/list', name: 'list', component: ListComponent },
      { path: '*', redirect: '/list'}
    ]);
    self.$router.push({name: 'create'}); // ok result: User data: { "name": "username" }; other prop:
    self.$router.push({name: 'list'}); // ok result: Listing

    // first attempt
    self.$router.push({name: 'create', props: {otherProp: {"a":"b"}}}) // not ok result: User data: { "name": "username" }; other prop:
    self.$router.push({name: 'list'}); // ok result: Listing

    // second attempt
    self.$router.push({name: 'create', params: {otherProp: {"a":"b"}}}) //not ok result: User data: { "name": "username" }; other prop:
  }
});
```

As you can see first I am passing to `CreateComponent` the `user` just when I initialize the route.

Later I need to pass another property `otherProp` and still keep the `user` parameter. When I try to do this the object I send is not passed to the component.

How can I pass the `otherProp` and still keep the `user`?

The real purpose of the `otherProp` is to fill a form with the data from it. In the listing part I have the object and when I click the "edit" button I want to populate the form with the data that comes from the listing.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It can work by using [props's Function mode](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/passing-props.html) and `params`

Vue 2 demo: https://jsfiddle.net/hacg6ody/

when adding routes, use [props's Function mode](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/passing-props.html) so that it has a default property `user` and it will add `route.params` as props.

```
{
    path: '/create',
    name: 'create',
    component: CreateComponent,
    props: (route) => ({
        user: userData,
        ...route.params
    })
}
```

params passed in push will automatically be added to props.

```
self.$router.push({
    name: 'create',
    params: {
        otherProp: {
            "a": "b"
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: and how one makes such params to appear in the url, for instance in "query" (pseudoquery, if that's not history mode of the router)?

Comment: Lost you on the line that is "...route.params". What are the three dots for?

Comment: @Craig that's https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: Note: The fiddle above no longer works as it seems to be using latest Vue version, and the fiddle is written in Vue 2. Use this one instead to get the Vue 2 one working: https://jsfiddle.net/hacg6ody/ I submitted an edit to the answer to help other readers. Old fiddle was: https://jsfiddle.net/jacobgoh101/mo57f0ny/1/

Answer (score 4):

I'm using the following setup in Vue Router 4 and Vue 3 and Composition API:

1. In the router, define your route like:

   ```
   {
     name: 'someroute',
     path: 'someroute?id=:id&name=:name`,
     component: [YourComponentNameHere],
     props: true,
   }
   ```
2. In the sender component:

   ```
   router.push('someroute',
     params: {
       id: 1,
       name: 'John'
     }
   })
   ```
3. In the receiver component, access them using:

   ```
   router.currentRoute.value.params.id
   router.currentRoute.value.params.name
   ```

Comment: Using vue3 (with ts) and your awnser worked. But I would like to pass an entire item for a list > edit feature. Did you find something

Comment: @jplattus: You can try `JSON.stringify()` to convert your item to a string and then pass it through `params` or even `query` option of Vue router.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my simple solution to send object using Router.

```
this.$router.push({
 name: 'someName'
 params: {
  obj: {...someObject}
 },
});
```

And if you want to use obj in the next page. You Can get data below.

```
this.$route.params.obj
```

Comment: this is an anti-pattern and will not work in the current version of vue-router