# Why doesn't Vue3 router not pass props with params?

Tags: vue.js, vue-props

I want to pass a value to a view as prop in Vue3.
This approach work well in Vue2 project but doesn't in Vue3

Router:

```
{      
  path: "/view2",
  name: "view2",
  component: View2,
  props: true
}
```

View 1 (from)

```
navigateTo(){
    this.$router.push({
      name: view2,
      params: {id: 'abc123'}
    })
}
```

View 2 (to)

```
props:{
  id:{
    type: String,
    required: false
  }
}
```

Each time the `navigateTo()` is called, the 'id' is undefined in View2

What am I missing cause this works well in vue2 project.

Best

Comment: Try to change: `params: {id: 'abc123'}` to: `props: {id: 'abc123'}` in router push.

Comment: Thanks but same result.

Comment: Please, check your `params` using `console.log(to)` on route changing.

Comment: All nicely there when logging from router level => params: { id: 'abc123' }

Comment: Vue 3? Are you using a preview build or something?

Comment: Its a large project, everything else works well and the same project is live, in production. Perhaps there is some configuration error although I am not aware of any that would only effect routing params.

Comment: Did you manage to get this working without having to add the params inside the url? I'm still struggling to get this working in Vue3

Answer (score 3):

You did not declare id in your path.

```js
{      
  path: "/view2/:id", // <----
  name: "view2",
  component: View2,
  props: true
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't need to pass path or query parameters. Need to pass values to props of the other view.

Comment: Take a look at this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50507329/8575814. Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: Is there a way to do it **without** having the params inside the URL? For instance there's 100 params I want as props using router - I don't any of them to be explicitly visible to the user in the URL

Comment: @parsecer Yes, see https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#boolean-mode. What is shown above is the "Boolean mode", but you can use the "Object mode" or "Function mode".

Comment: Did you manage to get this working without having to add the params inside the url? I'm still struggling to get this working in Vue3