# updating components when new params are passed to them (VUE JS)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

EDITED -

Best to start this over.

I have a VUE js CLI app - it calls the DB from the APP.vue page and then dispurses the data to the other pages and nav bar -

The nav bar calls a router function:

```
loadRouter(articles){
          this.$router.push({name: 'Articles', params: {articles: articles}})
      }
```

However this is now causing 2 issues:

1. the component does not re-load with  new data when a new nav is clicked
2. I receive an error:

   Error: Avoided redundant navigation to current location: "/articles".

[image]

The CODE:

app.vue <<<< this file makes the fetch call then passes that data to the component NAV bar (seen in `<Navbar :articleData="articleData"/>`)

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="topElements">
      <Navbar :articleData="articleData"/>
      
      <router-view/>
    </div>
      <Footer />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Navbar from '@/components/Nav.vue'

import Footer from '@/components/Footer.vue'
export default {
  components: {
    Navbar,
    Footer
  },
  data(){
    return {
      articleData: null,


      //   set up a variable for the local host as this will change later when the enviroment moves online
      enviroment: 'http://localhost:1337/',
    }
  },
  created(){
    fetch(`${this.enviroment}languages`)
    .then(responce => responce.json())
    .then(data => {this.articleData = data})
  }
}
</script>
```

Navbar.vue << this is where the user selects the language (article) - this is done via a @click event that then calls the callback which `$route.push` the Article component and props

```
template>
  <div class="navigationContainer">
      <div class="languageContainer" v-for="item in articleData" :key="item.id">
          <h2 @click="loadRouter(item.articles)">{{ item.title }}</h2>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Navbar',
  props: ['articleData'],
  data(){
      return{

      }
  },
  methods: {
      loadRouter(articles){
          this.$router.push({name: 'Articles', params: {articles: articles}})
      }
  } 
}
</script>
```

Articles.vue << lastly the articles page displays all the articles here by being passed as a prop the (the initial props does load but then does not re-load when a new nav is clicked and the error i mentioned above is shown)

Articles.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="articleContainer">
     <p>{{ articles }}</p>  <<< just to display if the props has come through correctly - will be changed later
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'Articles',
    props: ['articles'],
    data(){
      return{
        articleData: null,
      }
    },
    watch: {
      articles(){
        this.articleData = this.articles; <<<< trying to update the component when A new $route is detected - I also tried this with $route
        console.log(articleData) <<< checking if it worked.... 
      }
    }
}
</script>
```

Thats allot to read so I just wanted to say thank you for any help that can be given here.

Warm regards,
Wally

p.s.

Ask any questions you might have

EDITED:

article data from: http://localhost:1337/languages

Its an array of OBJS being pulled from the STRAPI API (I've made it public)

```
[
{
"id": 1,
"title": "JS",
"created_at": "2020-07-10T08:30:33.156Z",
"updated_at": "2020-07-10T08:30:33.156Z",
"articles": [
{
"id": 4,
"title": "hamburger menu",
"description": "This is where I would explain how to make a front end hamburger menu style for the navigation of a web page",
"created_at": "2020-07-10T08:32:11.474Z",
"updated_at": "2020-07-10T08:32:11.474Z"
}
]
},
{
"id": 2,
"title": "HTML",
"created_at": "2020-07-10T08:30:38.437Z",
"updated_at": "2020-07-10T08:30:38.437Z",
"articles": [
{
"id": 4,
"title": "hamburger menu",
"description": "This is where I would explain how to make a front end hamburger menu style for the navigation of a web page",
"created_at": "2020-07-10T08:32:11.474Z",
"updated_at": "2020-07-10T08:32:11.474Z"
},
{
"id": 5,
"title": "WEB STRUCTURE",
"description": null,
"created_at": "2020-07-10T10:08:44.221Z",
"updated_at": "2020-07-10T10:08:44.221Z"
}
]
},
{
"id": 3,
"title": "CSS",
"created_at": "2020-07-10T08:30:43.107Z",
"updated_at": "2020-07-10T08:30:43.107Z",
"articles": [
{
"id": 4,
"title": "hamburger menu",
"description": "This is where I would explain how to make a front end hamburger menu style for the navigation of a web page",
"created_at": "2020-07-10T08:32:11.474Z",
"updated_at": "2020-07-10T08:32:11.474Z"
}
]
},
{
"id": 4,
"title": "VUE",
"created_at": "2020-07-10T10:52:11.390Z",
"updated_at": "2020-07-10T10:52:11.390Z",
"articles": []
},
{
"id": 5,
"title": "NODE JS",
"created_at": "2020-07-10T10:52:23.351Z",
"updated_at": "2020-07-10T10:52:23.351Z",
"articles": []
},
{
"id": 6,
"title": "SASS",
"created_at": "2020-07-10T10:52:31.450Z",
"updated_at": "2020-07-10T10:52:31.450Z",
"articles": []
},
{
"id": 7,
"title": "PHP",
"created_at": "2020-07-12T19:21:48.620Z",
"updated_at": "2020-07-12T19:21:48.620Z",
"articles": []
},
{
"id": 8,
"title": "GIT",
"created_at": "2020-07-12T19:22:02.208Z",
"updated_at": "2020-07-12T19:22:02.208Z",
"articles": []
}
]
```

Comment: You're trying to pass an array through the route and it expects a primitive value.  You either need to use [function mode](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#function-mode) similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50506470/how-to-pass-an-object-as-props-with-vue-router) or pass just an id and do a lookup somewhere.

Comment: Thank you for the reply - I have altered my work to send a primitive through but it's not very efficient really - initially I have made a fetch requestion which loads all data on the nav bar - which then I wanted to pass via routes to the component, with this method I'm making multiple fetch requests..... which doesn't seem correct (but I'm very possibly wrong here) -- thanks again for the help

Comment: Hi Steve - thank you for your suggestion - I have followed this and made some changed to the code but now I am receiving errors - I have updated the question if you could re-vist it that would be amazing as I'm really lost here and have been going in circles for a while

Comment: I don't see the update to the question

Comment: Sorry Steven - I have just added the edit - any help would be great and sorry for the long read..... ask any questions you might have :)

Comment: Can you add what `articleData` looks like when it comes back from the api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your navbar can just use a normal `router-link` and bind the article to the params of the route.

**Navbar.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="navigationContainer">
      <div class="languageContainer" v-for="article in articleData" :key="item.id">
          <router-link :to="{name: 'Articles', params: { id: article.id, article: article }}">
            {{ article.title }}
          </router-link>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>
....
```

You'll need to update your route to use [function mode](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#function-mode) and parse out the article from the `route.params` to feed into your component as props.

**Routes**

```
{
    name: 'Articles',
    path: '/articles/:id', 
    props: (route) => ({
        id: route.params.id,
        article: route.params.article,
    })
}
```

And finally your article component will receive the `id` and `article` as props.

**Articles.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="articleContainer">
     <p>{{ id }}</p>
     <p>{{ article.title }}</p>
     <p>{{ article.description }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'Articles',
    props: ['id', 'article'],
    created() {
        if (!this.article) {
            // direct url navigation: you need to fetch the article using `this.id`
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

[Simplified Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/87t46hr2/)

One thing you'll need to consider.  If a user directly navigates to the route through the url, the `article` prop will be null.  So you'll need fetch the article in the component's `created` hook or a router navigation guard.

Comment: Awesome thank you for the feedback! I'll implement this shortly to see if it has success :) thank you for all of your effort on this question its really appreciated

Comment: Hi Steven - Just implemented this (had to take a break from the screen for a little while) - its all working as I had originally had hoped - Thank you again for your help on this issue, it seems I have some more learning to do with Vue.js and how to handle routes. I had originally used router-links instead of $route.push but had not known about the params function (or how to handle it) - this has been a great bit of learning for me! Thanks again for all your help and saving me from more grey hairs :P

Answer (score 0):

I might do this a little differently, as follows:

1. In App.vue, do not fetch the entire set of articleData.  Instead, just retrieve the item titles and item ids that the Navbar needs.
2. Then, in Navbar, just use a router-link to pass through the item.id:

````
          <router-link :to="{name: 'Articles', params: { itemid: item.id}}">
            {{ article.title }}
          </router-link>```
````

3. Then, in your Articles component, fetch the article details within the `mounted()` lifecycle method, keying off the `itemid`.
4. ***The final step addresses the title of the post, and is necessary to ensure that the Articles mounted lifecycle method fires even when the $route is seemingly unchanged***.  You do this by changing `<router-view>` to `<router-view :key="$route.fullPath">` in the App.vue file.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="topElements">
      <Navbar :articleData="articleData"/>
      
      <router-view :key="$route.fullPath" />
    </div>
      <Footer />
  </div>
</template>
```

While this approach requires two fetches instead of one, you will only be fetching the data required for the user's specific path.

Comment: This is actually how I would probably do it too but I would just use a `beforeRouteUpdate` in-component guard to fetch the new data rather than putting a key on the `router-view` and causing a complete re-render.