# Pass an object as param to router.push (vue-router@4.05)

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3, vue-router4

## Problem

`router.push({name:"Order", params: {obj: {}})`
fails to push `obj: {}`, instead the route receives `obj: '[object Object]'`

## Situation

I have a route setup like this

```
{
    path: '/Order',
    name: 'Order',
    component: () => import("../views/Order.vue"),
    props: route => {
      return route.params.obj //  '[object Object]'
    },
 }
```

this results in props not being defined in `Order.vue`

## Expected Result

```
{
    ...
    props: route => {
      return route.params.obj //  '{}'
    },
}
```

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50506470/) objects work in older versions

## What I've tested

I've used jest to inspect the arguments passed to `router.push` and they appear as they should: `{name:"Order", params: {obj: {}}`

Any Ideas?

Comment: Route params are strings in the URL (ie `/route/:param`). How do you expect this to serialise `{}` to a string?

Comment: I thought the same thing, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50506470/) seems to indicate that you can pass objects as params

Comment: That was asked 2 years ago about a much older version

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router-next/issues/494

Comment: Because it was possible, I want to know if it still is. Thanks for the github issue

Comment: Deprecated since [vue-router@4.1.4](https://github.com/vuejs/router/blob/main/packages/router/CHANGELOG.md#414-2022-08-22) (2022-08-22)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Passing objects to `params` was [never supported](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router-next/issues/494#issuecomment-698951187) in Vue-router

It sort of worked in Router v3 with `$router.push` - the target component received the object. **BUT** as soon as user started using browser navigation (Back button) OR copy/pasting URL's, this solution was broken (you can try it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/long-lake-zce24?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) - just click the button and then use back and forward controls of the frame)

As a rule of thumb - if you want to pass **anything** to the target route/component, such data must be defined as parameters in the route definition so it can be included directly in the URL. Alternatives are passing data in a store, query params (objects needs to be serialized with `JSON.stringify`), or using the history state.

This was true for Vue-router v3 and is still for Vue-router v4

**Note**

Just to explain alternatives. By "store" I do not mean just Vuex. I understand Vuex can be overkill for some small applications. I personally prefer [Pinia](https://github.com/posva/pinia) over existing Vuex. And you can create global state solution [yourself with composition API](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/state-management.html#simple-state-management-with-reactivity-api) very easily...