# vuejs router-link props send data

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I want to send data from home component via book.vue router link, but I am getting an error. Where am I doing wrong?

Home.vue

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            data: {
                attributes: {
                    name: 'Jonh',
                    age: '25',
                },
            },
        }
    },
}
```

router/index.js:

```
const routes =  [
    { path: '/Library/:id', name: 'Book', component: Book, props: true },
]
```

navigation:

```
:to="{ name: 'Book', params: { id: book.id}, props: { data: data.attributes} }"
```

Book.vue

```
export default {
  props: {
    id: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass an object as param to router.push (vue-router@4.05)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66864658/pass-an-object-as-param-to-router-push-vue-router4-05)

Comment: no this is not the answer i want

Comment: nor it is answer you deserve :) but jokes aside...passing objects via route params or query is not supported and **does not work**! Every param passed via router MUST be encoded in URL. End of discussion