# How to set and pass a JSON prop through routes

Tags: vue.js, router

In vue.js
route.js

```
[{path: "/path", name: "acomp_name", component: PathComp, props: { abc: {} }}]
```

comp.vue

```
<script>
...omitted_for_brevity,
methods: {
  changeRoute(json_sample){
     this.$router.push({name: "acomp_name", params: { abc: json_sample })
  }
}
</script>
```

1. Is there a way I can set the props which is an object to return json sample which is another object,  like this
   that is can I set the value of props of the router in a push
2. if indeed it is not supported in vue-router4 . what approach has been used or is being used to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass an object as param to router.push (vue-router@4.05)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66864658/pass-an-object-as-param-to-router-push-vue-router4-05)

Comment: no Sir, it does not, but seems close in the overview, the intent of my question is to even be able to see the values of props as an object being accessed in the first place, and quite honestly it returns the "[object object]", but I need to be a able to set and get  like where abc can be equal json_sample say for instance {"a": "stack", 'b': "overflow"},

Comment: Read it again .... **it is not possible to pass an object through route params** !

Comment: thanks I saw it well now, some last questions, do you really feel like Pinia  is really good over vuex, cause I noticed vuex is a bit slow especially for context commit changes, then what other alternatives do you advise with other third-party projects that can be used alongside vue.js n a project

Comment: Pinia is **really good**. It's author (posva) is Vue core member and Pinia was his side-project where he explored how "Vuex next" can look like. And indeed [current RFC of Vuex 5](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/discussions/270) (next version of Vuex) is very much inspired by Pinia

Comment: does that sound like we can still stick to vuex despite the odds since vuex is like a parent of pinia. especially with vuex5 coming forth,

Comment: Well, no. Vuex 4 is very different from Pinia. So if you are asking what will be easiest migration path I say Pinia to Vuex 5 will by much easier migration then Vuex 4 to Vuex 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am grateful to God Almighty for helping me to create an intuitive and reliable answer,
N<>B solution works with vue3 and vue-router4x

in the comp.vue
somewhere inside the template I have a nested or child component
so

```
    <template>
      <p>...</p>
    ...omitted_for_brevity
    <router-view :prop_from_router.js="this.state.a_key_I_want_to_use"/>
    </template>
```

still in comp.vue

```
<script>
...omitted_for_brevity
setup(){
  const s = reactive({})
  return {s}
},
methods: {
  changeRoute(t)
  this.state.a_key_i_want_to_use = t
}
}
</script>
```