# How to pass an object as props with Vue Router with Vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

How to pass an object as props in Vue 3 using the Vue Router? This can be achieved in Vue 2 following the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50506470/how-to-pass-an-object-as-props-with-vue-router) and its corresponding [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jacobgoh101/mo57f0ny/1/). In Vue 3 this syntax stringifies pushed objects into "[object Object]" in contrast to Vue 2. I have tried with Vue 3 in the following [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/asnjcmpx/103/).

```
const Home = { template: '<div>Home</div>',
               mounted: function() {
                this.$router.push({
                    name: "about",
                    params: {
                        user: "User Name",
                        objectParam: {a: "a"}
                    }
                  })
                }}
const About = { template: '<div>About</div>',
                                props: ['user', 'o', 'objectParam'],
                mounted: function(){
                    console.log( "Passed props:" )
                    console.log( this.$props )
                }}

const routes = [
  { path: '/', component: Home },
  { path: '/about', name:"about", component: About, 
                                  props: route => (
                                         console.log("Params defined here are passed as objects."),
                                         console.log("But route params object passed via push has already been stringified."),
                                         console.log(route.params),
                                         {o: {b: "b"},
                                          ...route.params
                                          })},
]


const router = VueRouter.createRouter({
  history: VueRouter.createWebHashHistory(),
  routes,
})

const app = Vue.createApp({})
app.use(router)
app.mount('#app')
```

Can objects be passed via Vue Router push() in Vue 3?

Answer (score 1):

I can't find any official documentation from Vue Router to support that and to be honest I don't think it's a great idea to send dynamic objects as params, but if you really want to do so, one way to achieve it is to stringify your object and then parse it on the receiver side. So something like this:

```
this.$router.push({
    name: "about",
    params: {
        user: "User Name",
        objectParam: JSON.stringify({ a: "a" })
    }
})
```

And then in the other component:

```
JSON.parse(this.$route.params.objectParam)
```

Comment: Thanks and sorry, I should have been more explicit. I was specifically aiming to avoid using JSON.stringify into JSON.parse here as the object that I was trying to pass is rather large and JSON.stringify is slow in this case.

Comment: I see, well as I mentioned you should not pass large objects via params in my opinion. If it feels that way it might be a flaw in your application design. Consider refactoring your code and use store or events instead.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going out on a limb and saying I don't think that's possible in Vue3.

You might take a look into a state manager like [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) and see if it solves your problem. The state manager concept will allow you to keep a complex object across multiple views.

Answer (score 0):

One more thing to note, besides stringifying, if we take this object from **Vuex** now in Vue3 **we will get a proxy**. Which also creates a trouble.

To solve this we need to transform proxy into a normal object first, for example with lodash `cloneDeep`.

```
router.push({
  params: {
    objFromVuex: JSON.stringify(cloneDeep(objFromVuex))
  }
});
```

In order to read the value, just `JSON.parse`

```
const objFromVuex = JSON.parse(this.$route.params.objFromVuex);
```